# Sum and Count Changes per Group for each Column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have seen examples of using lapply across columns, but not one that considers (1) a timestamp (2) groups based on timestamp (3) detects when values change

I'm looking for a way to do the follow for an arbitrary number of `Panels` per `Sensor` (there could be `Panel 3`, `Panel 4`, etc.):

- for each `year`, `month`, `hour`, I'm looking for the `sum` and `Counts Turn On` which is a count of the # times a value changes from 0 to a non zero number. To simplify, non-zero values at the start of the `hour` should not be counted towards this value (even if the previous value is 0).

take the `df`:

```
cols <- c("Timestamp","1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1","1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2")
tstmp <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-08-13 00:00:00", tz="US/Eastern"), 
             as.POSIXct("2018-08-13 03:30:00", tz="US/Eastern"), 
             by="15 min") %>% as.data.frame()
stage1 <- c(rep(c(0,.7,1),5)) %>% as.data.frame() 
stage2 <- c(0,1,rep(c(0,.5),5),0,1,1) %>% as.data.frame()

df = cbind(tstmp,stage1,stage2)
colnames(df) = cols
```

I'd like the result to be `results_1`:

```
ID                      Year    Month   Hour    Sum     Count Turn On
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1   2018        8   0       1.7         1
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1   2018        8   1       2.4         1
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1   2018        8   2       2.7         1
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1   2018        8   3       1.7         1
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2   2018        8   0       1.5         2
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2   2018        8   1       1           2
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2   2018        8   2       1           2
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2   2018        8   3       2           1
```

For those more ambitious, I'd like to see a solution that is able to determine whether the last reading in the previous hour was 0 and the first reading in the next hour is non-zero, and is able to count that towards `Count Turns On` -- the solution would look like below in `results_advanced`:

```
ID                      Year    Month   Hour    Sum     Count Turn On
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1   2018        8   0       1.7         1
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1   2018        8   1       2.4         2
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1   2018        8   2       2.7         1
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1   2018        8   3       1.7         1
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2   2018        8   0       1.5         2
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2   2018        8   1       1           2
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2   2018        8   2       1           2
1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2   2018        8   3       2           1
```

I'd like a solution for at least `results_1`, but would appreciate solutions for both `results_1` and `results_advanced`. Please provide any detail you can as to your thought process and this will help me (and others) learn more.

I believe there are both `data.table` and `dplyr` solutions so I'll tag both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `tidyverse` approach to the first problem. Hopefully you can use this to approach the second part of your question.

First we convert the data from [wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) with `gather` from `tidyr`. I also remove the Timestamp variable, but that's optional.

```
library(lubridate); library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>% 
  gather(ID, Val, -Timestamp)
head(df_long)
            Timestamp                    ID Val
1 2018-08-13 00:00:00 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1 0.0
2 2018-08-13 00:15:00 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1 0.7
3 2018-08-13 00:30:00 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1 1.0
4 2018-08-13 00:45:00 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1 0.0
5 2018-08-13 01:00:00 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1 0.7
6 2018-08-13 01:15:00 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1 1.0

df_long <- df_long %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Timestamp),
         Month = month(Timestamp),
         Hour = hour(Timestamp)) %>% 
  select(-Timestamp)
```

I then calculate the number of times turned on using `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::lag`, which allows you to access the previous value.

```
df_long <- df_long %>% 
  group_by(ID, Year, Month, Hour) %>% 
  mutate(Turned = ifelse(lag(Val) == 0 & Val != 0, 1, 0))
```

Then just use `dplyr::summarise` to calculate the final values. Note it is the `group_by` statement in this part is redundant, since we already grouped, but I keep it in there for clarity.

```
df_long %>% 
  group_by(ID, Year, Month, Hour) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(Val),
            NTurned = sum(Turned, na.rm = T))

  ID                     Year Month  Hour   Sum NTurned
  <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1  2018     8     0   1.7       1
2 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1  2018     8     1   2.4       1
3 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1  2018     8     2   2.7       1
4 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 1  2018     8     3   1.7       1
5 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2  2018     8     0   1.5       2
6 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2  2018     8     1   1         2
7 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2  2018     8     2   1         2
8 1000 Sensor 2 Panel 2  2018     8     3   2         1
```